# upload file to firebase storage not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I did read the doc over at [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) , but for some reason I cant get it to work.

I am using react and what I want is to be able to upload a file to my firebase storage, but I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: thisRef.put(...).then is not a function
```

I think I need different eyes on this.

Here is my function

```
uploadFile = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
  var file = this.refs.filePath.files[0];
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  //dynamically set reference to the file name
  var thisRef = storageRef.child(file.name);

  //put request upload file to firebase storage
  thisRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

The file uploads to the firebase storage, but it keep complaining about the promise (.then)

Here is the file that I am working on [GitHub](https://github.com/CyrusZei/sidekick/blob/master/src/sidekick/features/cloud/cloud.js)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Is there any way you can reproduce the problem in a jsbin, so we can have a look?

Comment: I updateded it with my gitHub repo, that might help? The file uploads to the fb Storage, but it is the promise that it complains about

Answer (score 1):

You can Try something like this

```
async function _UpdateImage(image) {
const response = await fetch(image);
const blob = await response.blob()
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const thisRef = storageRef.child("ProfilePhoto/" + user.uid);
    thisRef.put(blob).then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!',snapshot);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine on my environment. 
Try

```
console.log(thisRef.put(file));
```

and check `thisRef.put(file)` is Promise or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Firebase Test</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            // your configs
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="datafile">
    <script>
        function fileChange(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            var file = target.files[0];
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
            var thisRef = storageRef.child("public/" + file.name);
            thisRef.put(file).then(function (snapshot) {
                console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
            });
        }
        var inputFile = document.getElementById('file');
        inputFile.addEventListener('change', fileChange, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
thisRef.put(file).then(function (snapshot) {
            console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        });
```

to

```
const uploadFileToDb = async (e:any,file:File) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const storageRef = db.storage().ref();
    const fileRef = storageRef.child("files/"+file.name)
    fileRef.put(await file.arrayBuffer()).then(snapshot=> {
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    })
   
        
        
}
```

the put() methode expects an ArrayBuffer so i changed file to file.arrayBuffer()